# Clear grouping in ng-grid with external button

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-grid

I have a ng-grid with data that is grouped by category, as shown below:

```
$scope.gridOptions = {
  columnDefs: [
    {field: 'cat', displayName: 'Category'},
    {field: 'name', displayName: 'Name'},
    {field: 'val', displayName: 'Value'}
  ],
  data: 'myData',
  groups: ['cat']
}
```

I would like to be able to un-group the data in the ng-grid externally with a button. I do not want to display the group panel (via `$scope.gridOptions.showGroupPanel: true`), which provides an 'X' to clear the grouping.

I have tried executing the following when clicking on the external button without any success:

- `$scope.gridOptions.groups = [];`
- `$scope.gridOptions.groups.length = 0`

Any suggestions on how I can clear the grouping? Ultimately I would like to be able to make the grouping toggle on/off with the button; however, clearing the grouping seems like a good first step. Thanks for your help!

Here is a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kabb5/DVT95/11/)

Comment: Can you provide Plunker/Fiddle with your problem?

Comment: Are you using HTML5 or jQuery UI for table group?

Comment: @TiagoBarreto - HTML5, but since I don't want the group panel visible (therefore, no drag & drop), that shouldn't really matter

Comment: @MaximShoustin - added Fiddle to end of question (http://jsfiddle.net/kabb5/DVT95/11/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an undocumented function in the source code for programmatically setting groups. You can simply:

```
gridOptions.groupBy(columnFieldKey)
```

Unfortunately, I haven't been able to find a way to group by more than one column at a time, programmatically.

Comment: FANTASTIC! That was the ticket!
Here is he updated Fiddle --> http://jsfiddle.net/kabb5/DVT95/13/

Answer (score 1):

You can add columns to the existing grouped column by a series of group by statements.

```
gridOptions.groupBy(col1);
gridOptions.groupBy(col2);
```

You can clear the existing group by

```
gridOptions.groupBy(null);
```