# Grouping ng-grid by non-displayed column

Tags: javascript, angularjs, datagrid, ng-grid

Lets say I have an array of objects of the pattern

```
{
  name: ...
  age: ...
  dept: ...
}
```

And I want to show them on an ng-grid, but I only want columns for `name` and `age`

```
columnDefs: [{field:'name'...},{field:'age'...}
```

But I want them to be grouped by `dept`, *without showing a* `dept` *column.*

I've tried to just add a `groups: ['dept']` to my grid options, but that doesn't work - it just shows the grid without grouping.

I've also [seen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20201924/clear-grouping-in-ng-grid-with-external-button) a lot of people use `gridOptions.groupBy`, but when I try

```
$scope.gridOptions = ...
$scope.gridOptions.groupBy('dept')
```

I get an (expected) `undefined is not a function` error. I don't understand how people how people's examples work when `gridOptions` is just a plain old object.

So my question is: is it possible to group my ng-grid with a non-displayed column?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a hack around my problem. I defined the 'group by' column as normal, but I set the `width`, `minWidth`, and `maxWidth` to 0. Additionally, I set `resizeable` to false.

Answer (score 0):

you can use

```
$scope.gridOptions = {
    columnDefs: [ {field:'name'...}, {field:'age'...}, {field:'dept', visible:false }],    
    groups: ['dept']
}
```